# jsp pages path is not built to correct place

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss

I am creating my first web application using spring mvc and hibernate. When I generate war file(even without generating war, I also tried to deploy directly using in IDE itself and went to deployment folder and observed) my jsp files are placed under WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF\views. But I think this has to be WEB-INF\views. Can any one of you please help me with what I missed here?
Mi AppConfig class is"

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring.basics")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }}
```

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: The problem is at line 89, says my crystal ball.

Comment: @JBNizet: I am sorry if I dint provide more information. Can you please let me know what can I provide?

Comment: The problem happens, I quote "when I generate war file". So, you should tell how you generate the war file: what is the input (i.e. project layout), and the procedure. You also "think this has to be WEB-INF\views". So, also tell us why you think it should that and not, let's say "foo/bar".

Comment: @JBNizet: I updated my question, can you please let me know if I need to provide more information

Comment: So, you should tell how you generate the war file: what is the input (i.e. project layout), and the procedure.

Comment: @JBNizet: I am sorry if I irritating you.  My views structure is: srs/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153482/discussion-between-venkata-ramireddy-ch-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: How are you packaging your app?

Comment: I am not packaging it explicitly but just I am running my app on JBOSS directly from IDE. Then I went to deployments directory and finding this directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your deployment assembly for your project, I think Deploy Path is not / for your project:

[image]